# What is the meaning of て-forms in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, verbs, て-form, adjectives

While reading a travel blog I stumbled upon this paragraph:

> この日は－25℃。寒くて落ち着いて歩いていられません。

In my understanding, 寒くて is a て-form of 寒い, 落ち着いて is a て-form of 落ち着く, and 歩いて is a て-form of 歩く. However, I've never seen adjectives connected to verbs through the て-form, or verbs in て-form stuck one after another like that.

What is the grammar behind this and how to translate it?

Source of the sentence: https://www.asahi.com/and_travel/20200608/254241/ (see the 巨大なレーニンの頭像が part).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, "て" in "寒くて" plays a role of "so". Here is [an awesome article](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/i-adjective-te-form/). Refer to the part `〜くて FOR "SO"`.

> **寒くて**はっきりしゃべれない
> It's very cold **so** I can't speak clearly.

Next, "て" in "落ち着いて" works like adverbs. Also [awesome article](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-te-form-linking/). Refer to the part `て FORM FOR LINKING ACTIONS`.

> **落ち着いて**歩く
> walk **relaxedly**

The last "て" in "歩いて" works similarly by connecting "いられない"(can't bear). Or maybe it's negation of "歩いている" which is basic usage of て-form.
Thus it resolves the meaning like:

> 寒くて落ち着いて歩いていられない
> It's very cold so I can't put up with walking relaxedly.
> It's very cold so I can't keep walking relaxedly.